# Use Field Values For Filepath

Tags: php

I wonder whether someone may be able to help me please.

I'm trying to load an xml file with the following filepath:

```
/UploadedFiles/username/location/files.xml
```

What I've been trying to do for some time, is to use the values of two forms fields, 'username' and 'location' and incorporate them into the filepath, but I just can't seem to get this right.

I just wondered whether someone could someone perhaps tell me how I take these values and use them in the filepath.

Many thanks

**POST AMENDMENT**

I thought I could solve my issues by simply changing the file path, hence my original post, but I fear my lack of PHP knowledge as let me down and I suspect the issues I have are deeper within my code.

Please find below more detail.

The script below shows how I initially save the images.

**'upload.php'**

```
<?php
require_once 'Includes/gallery_helper.php'; 
require_once 'ImageUploaderPHP/UploadHandler.class.php'; 
$galleryPath = 'UploadedFiles/'; 

function onFileUploaded($uploadedFile) { 
  global $galleryPath; 

  $packageFields = $uploadedFile->getPackage()->getPackageFields(); 
  $username=$packageFields["username"]; 
  $locationid=$packageFields["locationid"]; 
  $username = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9_\-\.()\[\]{}]/i', '_', $_POST['username']); 
  $location = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9_\-\.()\[\]{}]/i', '_', $_POST['locationid']); 
  $dirName = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9_\-\.()\[\]{}]/i', '_', $_POST['folder']); 

  $absGalleryPath = realpath($galleryPath) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $username . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $location . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR; 
  $absThumbnailsPath = $absGalleryPath . 'Thumbnails' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR; 


  if (!is_dir($absGalleryPath)) mkdir($absGalleryPath, 0777, true); 
  chmod($absGalleryPath, 0777); 
  if (!is_dir($absGalleryPath . $dirName)) mkdir($absGalleryPath . $dirName, 0777, true); 
  chmod($absGalleryPath . $dirName, 0777); 

  if ($uploadedFile->getPackage()->getPackageIndex() == 0 && $uploadedFile->getIndex() == 0) 
    initGallery($absGalleryPath, $absThumbnailsPath, FALSE); 

  $originalFileName = $uploadedFile->getSourceName(); 
  $files = $uploadedFile->getConvertedFiles(); 
  $sourceFileName = getSafeFileName($absGalleryPath, $originalFileName); 
  $sourceFile = $files[0]; 

  if ($sourceFile) $sourceFile->moveTo($absGalleryPath . $sourceFileName); 
  $thumbnailFileName = getSafeFileName($absThumbnailsPath, $originalFileName); 
  $thumbnailFile = $files[1]; 
  if ($thumbnailFile) $thumbnailFile->moveTo($absThumbnailsPath . $thumbnailFileName); 

  $descriptions = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8'); 
  $descriptions->load($absGalleryPath . 'files.xml'); 

  $xmlFile = $descriptions->createElement('file'); 
  // <-- please check the following line 
  $xmlFile->setAttribute('name', $_POST['folder'] . '/' . $originalFileName); 
  $xmlFile->setAttribute('source', $sourceFileName); 
  $xmlFile->setAttribute('size', $uploadedFile->getSourceSize()); 
  $xmlFile->setAttribute('originalname', $originalFileName); 
  $xmlFile->setAttribute('thumbnail', $thumbnailFileName); 
  $xmlFile->setAttribute('description', $uploadedFile->getDescription()); 
  $xmlFile->setAttribute('username', $username); 
  $xmlFile->setAttribute('locationid', $locationid); 
  $xmlFile->setAttribute('folder', $dirName); 


  $descriptions->documentElement->appendChild($xmlFile); 
  $descriptions->save($absGalleryPath . 'files.xml'); 
} 

$uh = new UploadHandler(); 
$uh->setFileUploadedCallback('onFileUploaded'); 
$uh->processRequest(); 
?>
```

This script produces the following file structure:

UploadedFiles (Pre-existing folder)

- 'username' (Subfolder containing 'location' folder)
- 'location' (Subfolder containing original image, 'files.xml' and 'Thumbnails' folder)
- 'Thumbnails' (Subfolder containing thumbnail of original image)

**NB.** The 'username' and 'location folder names are derived from the current user and location values.

I then come onto my issue with the creation of the image gallery.

The code below is my initial 'gallery.php' script. I need to change the top PHP section of the script to match the new folder structure i.e. `UploadedFiles/'username'/'location'/Thumbnails` and `UploadedFiles/'username'/'location'.files.xml`

'gallery.php'

```
<?php 

  $galleryPath = 'UploadedFiles/'; 

  $thumbnailsPath = $galleryPath . 'Thumbnails/'; 

  $absGalleryPath = realpath($galleryPath) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR; 

  $descriptions = new DOMDocument('1.0'); 
  $descriptions->load($absGalleryPath . 'files.xml'); 
?>
<head> 
  <title>Gallery</title> 
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
  <link href="Libraries/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
  <link href="Styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
  <!--[if IE]>   
  <link href="Styles/ie.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
  <![endif]-->
  <script src="Libraries/jquery/jquery-1.4.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
  <script src="Libraries/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.1.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
  <script type="text/javascript"> 

  $(function() { $('a.fancybox').fancybox(); }); 

  </script> 
  <style type="text/css">
<!--
.style1 {
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-right: 110px;
}
.style4 {font-size: 12px}
-->
  </style>
</head>
<body style="font-family: Calibri; color:  #505050; font-size: 9px; border-bottom-width: thin; margin-top: 5px; margin-left: -476px; margin-right: 1px; margin-bottom: -10px;">
<div align="right" class="style1"> <a href = "imagefolders.php" /> View Uploaded Images In Folder Structure <a/> &larr; View All Uploaded Images </div>
  <form id="gallery" class="page"> 
  <div id="container"> 
    <div id="center"> 
      <div class="aB"> 
        <div class="aB-B"> 
          <?php if ('Uploaded files' != $current['title']) :?>
          <?php endif;?>
          <div class="demo"> 
          <input name="username" type="text" id="username" value="IRHM73" />
          <input name="locationid" type="text" id="locationid" value="1" />
            <div class="inner"> 
              <div class="container"> 
                <div class="gallery"> 
                  <ul class="gallery-image-list"> 
                  <?php for ($i = 0; $i < $descriptions->documentElement->childNodes->length; $i++) : 
                          $xmlFile = $descriptions->documentElement->childNodes->item($i); 
                          $name = htmlentities($xmlFile->getAttribute('originalname'), ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'); 
                          $description = htmlentities($xmlFile->getAttribute('description'), ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'); 
                          $folder = htmlentities($xmlFile->getAttribute('folder'), ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'); 
                          $source = $galleryPath . rawurlencode($xmlFile->getAttribute('source')); 
                          $thumbnail = $thumbnailsPath . rawurlencode($xmlFile->getAttribute('thumbnail')); 
                  ?>
                    <li class="item"> 
                      <a class="fancybox" target="_blank" rel="original" href="<?php echo $source; ?>"><img class="preview" 
                        alt="<?php echo $name; ?>"  src="<?php echo $thumbnail; ?>" /></a></li>
                        <p><span class="style4"><b>Image Description:</b> <?php echo htmlentities($xmlFile->getAttribute('description'));?> <br />
                          <b>Contained in folder:</b> <?php echo htmlentities($xmlFile->getAttribute('folder'));?> </span><br />  
                          <?php endfor; ?>
                          </li>
                        </p>
                  </ul>
                </div> 
              </div> 
            </div> 
          </div> 
        </div> 
      </div> 
    </div> 
    </div> 
        <div class="aB-a">        </div> 
      </div> 
    </div> 
  </div> 
  </form> 
</body> 
</html>
```

I admit to being at a real loss at how to solve this, I don't whether it's my 'gallery.php' script that needs to change or my 'upload.php'

Any help would be so gratefully received.

Kind regards

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, regular old concatenation would work. What have you tried?

Comment: You might edit this question to add more details. Without changing the topic of course.

Comment: Hi @Starx, just to let you know I have updated my post. Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

OK, let's say you have this values : `username`, `location`.

Then, (if I get your question right) in the responding script (the one receiving the form action), try this :

```
<?php

     $username = $_GET['username'];
     $location = $_GET['location'];

     $filepath = "/UploadedFiles/$username/$location/files.xml";

?>
```

---

**Hint *(2 ways of concatenating strings)* :**

```
$filepath = "/UploadedFiles/$username/$location/files.xml";
```

**OR**

```
$filepath = "/UploadedFiles/".$username."/".$location."/files.xml";
```

Comment: Hi, many thanks for this. Unfortunately I was unable to get this to work. However, having looked through my original post, I didn't provide enough details and I apologise for this. I have now added more detail to this. Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

This will work regardless you are using post or get method in your form . Just make sure you choose field name username and location for input text html element.

```
$filepath = "/UploadedFiles/{$_REQUEST['username']}/{$_REQUEST['location']}/files.xml"
```

Comment: Hi, many thanks for this. Unfortunately though, I couldn't get this to work, although I didn't receieve any error. However I think that it's my script and my lack of PHP knowledge rather than your code, I also feel that my original post didn't contain enough detail, apologies for this. I have now added to this. Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

You have to define them as variable and include within the string

```
$username = "user1";
$location = "userlocation1";

$url = "/UploadedFiles/$username/$location/files.xml";

//Next you might want to verify the location

if(is_file($url)) {
   //do your operation....
}
```

Comment: Hi, many thanks for this. Unfortunately, I couldn't get this to work, but having looked through my original post, I didn't provide enough details, and I apologise for this so I have raised a new post. Kind regards

Comment: @IRHM, Which one is your post?

Comment: many thanks for your reply, I'll amend the post in a few minutes. Kind regards